# How to add downloaded SDK to Intellij library / modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've downloaded the VMware API Java SDK and need to add it to the dependent modules in Intellij. These are the steps I take -

1. Download the SDK, this is a zip file containing a range of jar, java , files, documentation and samples.
2. Unzip the zip file locally
3. Go to project structure in Intellij and select Libraries
4. Add the root directory as a library (I am ok with this as a Project level library)
5. Go to Modules and Dependencies to confirm the new library is in the dependencies list

I then run the script which contains several import statements identifying classes that are in the SDK ie

```
import com.vmware.vcenter.VM
```

I get the error message "unable to resolve class ........" for all the SDK specific classes.

I have got round this in the past with other SDKs by finding and downloading the actual jar files but this is making extra work for myself when I believe I should be able to just use the downloaded zip file. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: The extracted zip needs to be on the classpath... You've configured something in the IDE wrong. Can you not use Maven/Gradle?

Comment: Re-import the project and Intellij will recognize the modules.

Comment: Man, it’s 2018, no one unzips filed on classpath anymore. Use a build tool

Comment: @cricket_007 is closest to my very basic error. I had downloaded the wrong SDK and none of the classes were in it.

Comment: However, while I can now get it to work I still can only seem to do this by expanding the zip file and finding the correct jar file through further expansion of jar files to find the correct classes then adding these jar files as modules in the project. Adding the zip file as a library fails. Note that while I can use maven in Intellij, I only use the IDE as a test bed as I then take the code (and required jar files) and copy it into a different platform that cannot recognise maven repositories.

Comment: "that cannot recognise maven repositories"... Well, that's a problem because Maven is a cross-platform build tool. Maybe you should add Maven Wrapper to your project

Answer (score 2):

For the future, you really should consider using a build-tool like Gradle or Maven. In the meantime, the easiest solution is to use IDEA's feature to create a maven library. However, it is unavoidable that you know which exact library you need.

You can go to *project structure* -> libraries and click on the + sign to create a new Maven library. In the window, you search for your library like this

[image: img]

You can then specify the folder and include sources and docs if you like and IDEA will take care of everything else. It's equal than extracting zips on your own, only faster and it will take care of dependencies.